# JS: get 5 items each time from whole array and get average

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, average

I have an array e.g.
`var arr = [2,7,3,8,9,4,9,2,8,7,9,7,3,2,4,5,7,8,2,7,6,1,8];`

I want that (I think for-loop is best for this to loop over this) a for-loop loops over the whole array and gets 5 items near eachother in the array and runs a function with those 5 items to calculate an average of them. This has of course to repeat till there are no parts of 5 available. The array above has 23 values. So when I should run a code on it, it can loop 4 times on it, cos one more time can't cos it has 3/5 values.

I thought about doing:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    doThisFunction(i, i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4 );
}
```

but that shouldn't be efficient I believe... any help?

Comment: you need to do `i+=5` instead of `i++` then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on to something, the easy way to do it is

```js
var arr    = [2,7,3,8,9,4,9,2,8,7,9,7,3,2,4,5,7,8,2,7,6,1,8];
var result = [];

for (var i=0; (i+5)<arr.length; i=i+5) {
    var average = (arr[i] + arr[i+1] + arr[i+2] + arr[i+3] + arr[i+4]) / 5;
    result.push(average);
}

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

The somewhat fancier way to do the same thing

```
var result = arr.map(function(x,i) {
    return i%5===0 ? arr.slice(i, i+5).reduce(function(a,b) {return a+b}) / 5 : NaN;
}).filter(isFinite);
```

Comment: Why not remove the `if` and do `for(var i=0; (i+5) < arr.length; ...)` instead?

Comment: You could return `NaN` and use `isFinite` as filter to fix the `0` part in the fancy version

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 - Good idea, I couldn't think of anything that would be true with a zero, even `filter(Number)` would fail that, but `isFinite` works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array.slice`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(arr.length/5); i++) {
    f(arr.slice(i*5, i*5+5))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following uses reduce and a slice to sum up a range of values from the array.

```js
function averageRange(arr, start, end) {
  return (function(range) {
    return range.reduce(
      function(total, val) {
        return total + val;
      }, 0) / range.length;
  }([].slice.apply(arr, [].slice.call(arguments, 1))))
}

function averageEveryN(arr, n) {
  return arr.map(function(_, index, arr) {
    return index % n === 0 ? averageRange(arr, index, index + count) : NaN;
  }).filter(isFinite).slice(0, Math.floor(arr.length / n));
}

function println(text) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += text + '<br />';
}


var arr = [2, 7, 3, 8, 9, 4, 9, 2, 8, 7, 9, 7, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 2, 7, 6, 1, 8];
var count = 5;

averageEveryN(arr, count).map(function(value, index) {
  println((index + 1) + '.) ' + value.toFixed(4));
});
```

### Output

```
1.) 5.8000
2.) 6.0000
3.) 5.0000
4.) 5.8000
```